# How to do this seemingly basic step in Terminal, "Add Homebrew to your PATH"?

Tags: ruby, command-line, terminal, homebrew, apple-m1

I am completely new to this kind of task. I'm hoping someone can give me a simple step-by-step translation of this message in Terminal, trying to install Homebrew to my M1 MacBook :

...

- Add Homebrew to your PATH in `/Users/amyk/.profile`:

  ```
  echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/amyk/.profile
  eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
  ```

...

Comment: That documentation gives you the exact commands to make it happen.  Simply copy the entire first line and then paste it into your Terminal app and then press return.  The second line doesn't really do anything.  After you do that, you will need to restart that terminal shell.  (Not necessarily the entire Terminal app, but that would do it.)

Comment: Thanks Ryan. when I tried that originally it gave me an error message, then I did a bunch of desperate things that didn't seem to help, thought I had messed everything up, and gave up. But just now your message gave me courage so I tried again and it worked! !!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can just run the two commands shown in the message in your terminal. That way, homebrew will be correctly setup for your currently running shell as well as any new shells you open.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I tried that, doesn't do anything. I just found this instruction on a web page commenting on this step in the process, not entirely sure what it means either: "create a ~/.zprofile file which contains a command which sets up Homebrew. Homebrew shows instructions at the end of the installation process" Does this mean I should paste the commands into a text file and save it as .zprofile in my user directory?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be missing the statement `(echo;` at the beginning of the command.

The following command worked for me. I hope this helps!
*Please be sure to replace the placeholder `YOUR_USER_NAME` with your path's user name*

```
(echo; echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"') >> /Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/.zprofile
    eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```